# How to delete rows of numpy array by multiple row indices?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists of indices (`idx[0]` and `idx[1]`), and I should delete the corresponding rows from numpy array `y_test`.

y_test

```
12  11  10
1   2   2
3   2   3
4   1   2
13  1   10

idx[0] = [0,2]
idx[1] = [1,3]
```

I tried to delete the rows as follows (using `~`). But it didn't work:

```
result = y_test[(~idx[0]+~idx[1]+~idx[2])]
```

Expected result:

result =

```
13  1   10
```

Comment: not `+`, but `&` for boolean AND operation

Comment: what was `~[0,2]` supposed to do?  `[0,2]+[1,3]` works to join 2 lists producing `[0,2,1,3]`.

Comment: If `idx` is a numpy array, using the bitwise negation operator on it is *not* doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing elements, just make a new array with the desired ones. This will keep any future indexing from getting jumbled up and maintain the old array.

```
import numpy as np
y_test = np.asarray([[12, 11, 10], [1, 2, 2], [3, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2], [13, 1, 10]])
idx = [[0, 2], [1, 3]]

# flatten list of lists
idx_flat = [i for j in idx for i in j]

# assign values that are NOT in your idx list to a new array
result = [row for num, row in enumerate(y_test) if num not in idx_flat]

# cast this however you want it, right now 'result' is a list of np.arrays
print result

[array([13,  1, 10])]
```

For an understanding of the flatten step using list comprehensions [check this out](https://coderwall.com/p/rcmaea/flatten-a-list-of-lists-in-one-line-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) which deletes the subarrays along the axis.

```py
np.delete(y_test, idx, axis=0)
```

Make sure that `idx.dtype` is an integer type and use [numpy.astype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) if not.

Your approach did not work because `idx` is not a boolean index array but holds the indices. So `~` which is binary negation will produce `~[0, 2] = [-1, -3]` (where both should be numpy arrays).

I would definitely recommend reading up on the difference between [index arrays](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) and [boolean index arrays](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays). For boolean index arrays I would suggest using [numpy.logical_not](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.logical_not.html#numpy.logical_not) and [numpy.logical_or](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html).

`+` concatenates Python lists but is the standard plus for numpy arrays.

Comment: This solution gives me weird result. In my real data set the shape of `y_test` is (60000,1). Then the length of `idx` is 6000. Thus I expect the result of `np.delete(y_test, idx, axis=0)` to have the shape (54000,1), but it is `56846 `

Comment: Without the actual data I can only guess, but maybe the entries in idx are not unique. You can try numpy.unique and compare the sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using NumPy I'd suggest masking in this way.

---

**Setup:**

```
import numpy as np

y_test = np.array([[12,11,10],
                   [1,2,2],
                   [3,2,3],
                   [4,1,2],
                   [13,1,10]])

idx = np.array([[0,2], [1,3]])
```

---

**Generate the mask:**

Generate a mask of ones then set to zero elements at index in `idx`:

```
mask = np.ones(len(y_test), dtype = int).reshape(5,1)
mask[idx.flatten()] = 0
```

---

**Finally apply the mask:**

```
y_test[~np.all(y_test * mask == 0, axis=1)]
#=> [[13  1 10]]
```

`y_test` has not been modified.

Comment: What do you mean?